# Map public container port for few private in Rancher

Tags: docker, haproxy, rancher

How to map single public port of container for few private ports in `Rancher Cattle` to make port sink? Maybe i should write custom `HAProxy` config?

For example:

```
5555/tcp -> 5555/tcp
5555/tcp -> 5556/tcp
5555/tcp -> 5557/tcp
5555/tcp -> 5558/tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is easily possible in Rancher.

One of the ways of implementing this:

1. "Add Stack" in Rancher
2. "Add Service" `one` (which has the tcp service running on port `5555`) to the stack.
3. "Add Service" `two` (which has the tcp service running on port `5556`) to the stack.
4. "Add Service" `three` (which has the tcp service running on port `5557`) to the stack.
5. "Add Service" `four` (which has the tcp service running on port `5558`) to the stack.
6. "Add Load Balancer" to this stack and configure it.

   - Add port Rule with protocol: `tcp`, port: `5555` with target to `one`,
     port: `5555`
   - Add port Rule with protocol: `tcp`, port: `5555` with target to `two`, port: `5556`
   - Add port Rule with protocol: `tcp`, port: `5555` with target to `three`, port: `5557`
   - Add port Rule with protocol: `tcp`, port: `5555` with target to `four`, port: `5558`

If you want this load balancer to run on all hosts, you can choose that option when creating the load balancer service.

Also if your service was running on HTTP instead of TCP, you could use that option as well.

Once you have this working manually you can "View Config" to get the `docker-compose.yml` and `rancher-compose.yml` files. You can use them to create your custom catalog item and deploy it in one click!

Check out the [community-catalog](https://github.com/rancher/community-catalog) for inspiration and the [docs](http://docs.rancher.com/) for instructions.